# similarity percentage of two images by EMGU.CV

Tags: c#, machine-learning, image-processing, pattern-matching, emgucv

I work on x-ray images, and i want to get the similarity percentage between two monochrome images using emgu.cv library on c#.
the attached file contain the two images which i need to find the similarity percentage.

any one help me to find the solution of that by machine learning or any another approch?

[image]

Comment: You could use matchTemplate or MMSI. What is EMGU?  I do not see any OpenCV module for that.

Comment: @fmw42 Emgu.CV is a C# wrapper of OpenCV :)

Answer (score 0):

EMGU.CV is same library in C# for openCV in C++ and python

you can use matchtemplate

In openCV it is

```
Mat image1Img = imread("image1.png", IMREAD_COLOR);
Mat image2Img = imread("image2.png", IMREAD_COLOR);
Mat image3Img = imread("image3.png", IMREAD_COLOR);

Mat scoreImg;
double maxScore;

matchTemplate(image1Img, image2Img, scoreImg, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
minMaxLoc(scoreImg, 0, &maxScore);
wxLogMessage(wxString::Format("score <%.2f>", maxScore));
```

In C# you can use as

```
Image<Gray, Byte> sourceImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(@"Images/Source.bmp");
Image<Gray, Byte> templateImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(@"Images/Template.bmp");
Image<Gray, float> resultImage = sourceImage.MatchTemplate(templateImage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
```

Detail can be checked [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/ee43f981-70ee-04c2-4c10-764da38f0781.htm)

Comment: thanks Imran for your answer, which value or parameter represent the percentage of similarity?

Comment: In open CV maxScore represents the percentage of similarity. I think it will be between 0 and 1. You can verify that.
In C# you have to process the resultImage to find the maximum score. Just check the values of resultImage you will find the clue.
If you like the answer please accept it and also click the useful

Comment: Imran, thank you very much, your response is useful. i tried it, it's good approche for the rbg images and grayscale, but i decided to develop my own algorithm for get the similarity percentage between 2 monochrome images.Tell me please where i can accept your answer and click the useful, i dont see this button? i new here in this site

Comment: You are welcome. You can just click up-button on left side of my answer to make it useful and you can click the tick ✅ below that button to accept it. Good luck for you algorithm. Do share with us your algorithm and share it on GitHub so that all can get benefit from it